# Does MappedByteBuffer use mmap under linux?

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

Very simple question, assuming the case under Linux, **not** windows.

If I try to get a MappedByteBuffer for a huge file with a buffer size very large, will JVM use virtual memory underneath?

Also, will MappedByteBuffer really have page fault? Should I make sure RAM has the free space as the appointed buffer size?

Comment: What do you mean by "really have page fault"? Page faults happen all the time in VM systems, and they're nothing to worry about.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense: when you `mmap` a file, that file becomes part of your process virtual address space. If you don't have enough virtual address space (eg, trying to map a 2Gb file on a 32-bit system), the mapping will fail.

Comment: What is the *real* problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `MappedByteBuffer` clearly states:

> A direct byte buffer whose content is a memory-mapped region of a file.

On a POSIX system, this means that the JRE will be using `mmap` to map the file's contents into memory. Unless the file is already present in memory for some reason, this will result in a page fault on the first access for each missing page, and a virtual-memory system can encounter page faults at any time for any allocated memory. Monitor system I/O to see whether you have enough RAM in the system running the application, but the kernel is good at determining when to swap contents in and out if necessary.

Comment: as long as the size I give is smaller or equal than the free ram+virtual_mem, then it should be fine?